# php every sixth row add class

Tags: php

I have a mysql query which selects 18 items from the table, but I'd like it to add a class on every 6th item.

Here's my code:

```
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($this->Items as $item) {

    if ($item->image) { 

            echo '<div class="storeImages"> <img src="/images/store/'.$item->image.'" width="113" height="153" border="0" alt="'.$item->name.'" title="'.$item->name.'" /> </div>';

    };

 $i++;
 };
```

I've tried a couple of different things, but can't seem to get it working, basically on each 6th item, I want to add style="margin-right: 0px;" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if($i % 6 == 0){
    //add class
}
```

Take a look at the [arithmetic operators](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Mod function (%)

somthing like.

```
if($i % 6 == 0)
```

edit: beaten to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$style = '';

if ($i % 6 == 0) {
  $style = ' style="margin-right: 0px;"';
}

echo '<div class="storeImages" ' . $style . '> <img src="/images/store/'.$item->image.'" width="113" height="153" border="0" alt="'.$item->name.'" title="'.$item->name.'" /> </div>';
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `$style` back to empty for the non-multiple of 6 lines!

Answer (score 0):

Modulo is your friend.